# How select specific tag in jQuery using if else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to click the button and make the value appear in `<h3>` inside the `<div>` and according to that value the `background-color` would change.

For example, when I typed a value (`Your number`) and clicked on `Click Me!`, `h3` inside the `div` should show this typed value and the background-color would also change accordingly.

For example, if I typed `33` in `Your number` and then clicked, the value to appear would be 33 and the color would be orange. Thus:

[image]

My code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform">
  Your number: 
  <input type="text" name="inputbox" id='textBox' value="" />
  <input type="button" name="button" class="member" value="Click me!" />
  <div class='box1' style='background-color:lime;width:33.33%;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;'>
    <h3>
    0
    </h3>
    <p>
    Valor
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  $(function() {

    $('.member').click(function() {
      var answer = $("#textBox").val();
      if (answer <= 20) {
        $('.box1').css('background-color','red');
      } else if (answer <= 50) {
        $('.box1').css('background-color','orange');
      } else {
        $('.box1').css('background-color','steelblue');
      }
    });

  });

</script>
```

So I wanted to select the `h3` tag and change it with `if else` statement.

Comment: Simply use : `$('.box1 > h3').text(answer);` to set value of h3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you simply want to update the `h3` tag content?

Here is some code (I removed repetitions):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.member').click(function() {
      let answer = $("#textBox").val();
      let color;
      if (answer <= 20) {
        color = 'red';
      } else if (answer <= 50) {
        color = 'orange';
      } else {
        color = 'steelblue';
      }
      
      $('.box1').css('background-color',color).find('h3').html(answer);
      
    });

  });
```